# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoModulesCore.NativeModulesProxy.ExponentConstants')

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I've been working on an App for a little while and everything went smoothly until metro stopped working altogether. Ngl i cannot really tell you what went wrong but this is the output in the terminal:[refer to the link][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPWIx.png
The code itself builds but i have no clue what goes wrong in the process.
Thanks in advance for any tip or advice you may have!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello there, do you have any new position to this problem ? Ihave the same problem here, while i was update from 42 to 46 Expo SDK.